# Emojis in jspdf doesnt works

Tags: jspdf

I'm trying to display emojis like: ✨test✨
in my pdf. But it doesnt works.

I already tryed adding a custom font with:

```
const font = "data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAANAIAAAwBQRkZU...."
doc.addFileToVFS("unifont-15.0.01.ttf", font);
doc.addFont("unifont-15.0.01.ttf", "Unifont", "normal");
doc.setFont("Unifont"); // set font
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution on how to display emojis using jsPDF?

Comment: @waanderer unfortunately no

Comment: did you use an alternative library instead of jsPDF or you just set the encoding of the emoji as a limitation?

Comment: I only tried with jspdf and dont found a way to support emojis